# Permission Denied on httplib2 install

Tags: python, terminal, httplib2

I'm trying to install the httplib2 library for Python so I can use it to interact with the Twitter but I get the following error in the console when I try to install via 'python setup.py install'.

This is a new MBA and I am the only user (and Admin) so I shouldn't get denied so rudely!

```
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2': Permission denied
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`sudo`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/sudo/) to run `setup.py` as root:

```
% sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 8):

Some say that using `sudo` on `python setup.py install` can be dangerous. Instead, run `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7`.

TL;DR; Using [Virtualenv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/) also happens to avoid this problem.